# Website magento theme install didn't go as planned

Tags: css, magento, shopping-cart

So, i'm building a website using magento, i tried to install a theme but there are some files that dont seem to be loading, including some css, i'm gonna list the website and the demo of the theme so you guys can tell me if you see something where you can help:

[The website](http://loja.delladonna.pt)

[The Demo](http://magresponsive.devdemoz.com/)

As you can see, there is a lot going wrong... the name of the divs isnt even the same, i have followed the readme tutorial and done this multiple times, the theme was installed using magento connect.

I've done the whole System>Configuration>Design and pointed to the new theme...

If you could give me some clue about what's wrong, i'd be very thankful, any further details needed, just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Package from Magento Connect includes only design and skin files without [WebAndPeople Custommenu](http://web-experiment.info/webandpeople-custom-menu-extension) extension.
2. Which names of divs do you see as not similar? I installed this theme for test and it is similar to yours with div names. **Don't look on the devdemoz.com's demo because it is modified theme and is not original that included in package!** You can compare their style.css and your with `diff` or `notepad++` to find differences (about 20% of original skin).
3. Footer. You made mistake in HTML code and placed tag `<h3>` outside of `<ul>`. Just move them one line down like in **/readme.html** file.
4. If you wish to use modified mobileshoppe demo from devdemoz.com you can simply grab their style.css and images and put in your folder.

Comment: will try that, seems like it might be it... How can i download all the images in the demo? is there an easy way? knowing i have no ftp access to their servers, obviously

Comment: visible images you may save as file => save full page in html+images (depends on browser you use). Images from css needs to be gnenerated as links (notepad++ can help you speeding process)

Comment: About your point 3, i copied directly from the readme, so i dont know if it was magento's wysiwyg editor or if they have it wrong in the readme

Comment: ok, so almost everything works fine after what you said, it was really magento's wysiwyg on the footer links... If you look at the links again    though, there's just 2 things missing, the page wide column, like the demo, and the menu disappeared when i changed the css, can you just give me a little help with that? Thanks

Comment: http://loja.delladonna.pt/downloader/.cache/community/ I don't see installed WebAndPeople Custommenu here... why did you use javascript with it? Look at your `frontend/default/mobileshoppe/template/page/html/header.phtml` and verify that it has `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>`. If it is not there add in bottom of the `div class=header` else look in `topmenu.phtml` for right content. You can get original theme template by uppper link and compare listed here files that referenced to menu. What do you mean about the page wide demo? Btw, I recommend to disable listing /downloader/

Comment: Dont know why man, i installed through magento connect like the tutorial said, everything like the tutorial said...
I will look at that though

Comment: the column being as wide as the whole page, thats what i mean, 100% width.
About the menu, it happened when i changed the css files, you think i should install it again?

Comment: As I see you have got topmenu now. About column - you need to change template layout design to 2 or 3 columns in CMS => Pages => Home => [Design]. Useful could be developer copy and production. Always make backup of files and log your changes to have rollback availability.

Comment: yeah, as of now, i was able to do everything my client wants me to, there's just one problem with the login now, i cant login, i can create an account and i will be logged in, but if i log out, i cant log back in, also, even if i create the account and login, i cant checkout... I promise i will bother you no more after this xD

Comment: Challenge accepted xD Add <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?> on 41 line in `frontend/default/mobileshoppe/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml`

Comment: F***in lifesaver! You're amazing! Thanks a lot man! :D Heartfelt! you don't know for how long i've been fiddling with this website... :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60753/discussion-between-antero-duarte-and-p0zitr0n).